# How to use google map apis in unity , c#

Tags: c#, google-maps, unity-game-engine, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

Can someone tell me how to use google map api in unity.
I know how to use static map because it is a image, but another API are return json, how can I use it, how to display route in unity, I only find way for java, how to do in c# , unity.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start

Comment: what do you try?

Answer (score 1):

You want to handle the incoming json by for example:
Deserialize the returned json into a class and work with your results.

[Google Maps Platform 
Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/) - Has all the request parameters and examples you need.

You can also use libraries like  [gmaps-api-net](https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net)

HowTo Webrequest: [Microsoft WebRequest Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class)

This is an example of how I use a weather api connected to unity.
It's collecting the data i need from my location, depending on the weather where I am, it either starts snowing/raining or being sunny/cloudy.
You can use google maps api the same way. Collect, provide and repeat.

```
    private async Task<WeatherInfo> GetWeather()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("http:/g/data/2.5/weather?id=" + CityId + "&APPID=" + API_KEY));

    WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    WeatherInfo info = JsonUtility.FromJson<WeatherInfo>(jsonResponse);
    string weatherString = info.weather[0].main;       
    return info;
```